# "Select all" option for Azure DevOps variable group linked to KeyVault

Tags: azure-devops, command-line-interface, devops, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I am running several YAML pipelines and use variable groups for this. I have a number of variable groups and each needs to be linked to a keyvault, and all secrets in that keyvault need to be added to the variable group.

In the documentation ([variablegroup documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)) it only gives the option to click on the "+Add" button and select each secret by hand. This takes up a lot of time, since there are a lot of secrets that need to be added.

Does anyone know of an option to select all secrets in a keyvault to add to a variable group?
Preferably from a powershell or CLI script.

Thanks for your help!

[EDIT]: I apologize for the confusing use of the word "secrets" before. I am looking to link the variable group to a **KeyVault** and add the secrets that are in there.

Comment: Did you look at the REST API documentation?

Comment: Or `az devops` CLI documentation?

Comment: I only now noticed the confusing way I worded the question. I did look at that documentation, but I am looking for a way to add all secrets that are in a linked key vault to the variable group in an automated way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API [Variablegroups - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to batch set variables in a variable group.

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{groupId}?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

P.S. The id of a variable group is an integer and increase from 1 in the order they were created. You can aslo get the id of a variable group using the REST API [Variablegroups - Get Variable Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get%20variable%20groups?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

to get all variable groups of your project and find the specific variable group id that you want.

Here is an example of the REST API's request body:

```
{
    "name": "{variable group name}",
    "variables": {
        "A": {
            "isSecret": false,
            "value": "a"
        },
        "B": {
            "isSecret": true,
            "value": "b"
        },
        "C": {
            "isSecret": true,
            "value": "c"
        }
    },
    "variableGroupProjectReferences": [
        {
            "description": "",
            "name": "{variable group name}",
            "projectReference": {
                "id": "",
                "name": "{project name}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I only now noticed that I didn't word my question very well. I am looking to link the variable group to a key vault and add all the keyvault secrets to the variable group without having to select each individually. Do you also know of a way to do this?